# Does NAPT track the outgoing packet protocol?

Tags: nat

If a machine sends a UDP packet to some destination over the internet, and that destination sends a packet to the source address in a protocol that is not UDP, will the router forward that packet to the machine or drop it?

Comment: Ports are per protocol. TCP port 9876 is not the same port as UDP port 9876. Some layer-4 protocols do not use port numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "router" always forwards a packet when it can, ie. has a routing entry to apply. It doesn't care about the L4 protocol used nor its state.

It depends on what your understanding of "router" is. A simple router just forwards but with firewall rules, NAT and other functions applied, forwarding may or may not occur.